# Create a PDA for the given language

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

The task is to create a PDA for this language. The **|u|** a reffers to the number of a's in that word. I have tried working on it as two separate languages that I can later combine, but I fail to even do any of the two.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention splitting $L$ in two different languages and combining the resulting PDAs, I assume you are fine with nondeterministic PDAs.

Let me show you a context-free grammar for $L$ instead (there are standard and completely mechanical ways to convert CFG grammars to PDAs).

Let $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ and split $L$ into two languages $L_1 = \{ uv \in \Sigma^* : 3|u|_a = |v|_b + |v|_c \}$ and $L_2 = \{ uv \in \Sigma^* : |u|_c = 2|v|_a \}$.
We can then design a context-free grammar for $L_1$ and $L_2$ separately.

A CFG for $L_1$ is the following (where the axiom is $S_1$):
$$
\begin{align*}
S_1 &\to XS_1A \mid aS_1YAYAY \mid \epsilon \\
X & \to bX \mid cX \mid \epsilon \\
A & \to aA \mid \epsilon \\
Y & \to b \mid c
\end{align*}
$$

A CFG for $L_2$ is the following (where the axiom is $S_2$):
$$
\begin{align*}
S_2 &\to WS_2Z \mid cWcS_2a \mid \epsilon \\
W & \to aW \mid bW \mid \epsilon \\
Z & \to bZ \mid cZ \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

To get a grammar for $L$, it suffices to combine the former two Grammars and add the production $S \to S_1 \mid S_2$ (where $S$ is the new axiom).

Comment: Thank you. We haven't taken that material yet, but I guess I will take in advance. :)